# Phonegap / Android App - Loss of web connectivity switching from wifi / data?

Tags: android, cordova

We seem to have a intermittent issue with an app we just launched - it relies on a internet connection as it shows payment screens in a iframe.  All works fine on wifi, switch over to 3g -  all works fine on, switch back to wifi again and it loses it connection - we just get popup errors saying it cant access the url!?

The app is compiled in Andoird 2.2.  We have no idea where to begin resolving and wonder whether its a bug with the HTC desire test phone or a wider issue.

Has anyone experienced this or has any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the Network code on PhoneGap Android and I can tell you that it takes awhile to establish a wifi connection. Going from wifi to 3G is pretty seamless but going from 3G to wifi actually does 3G -> no connection -> wifi. When I get a no connection even on Android I delay sending the offline event for half a second. If I don't get an online event by the end of timer I send the offline event.

It seems like you are seeing the same behaviour as I have seen but I'm not too sure how to fix your issue as you are embedding an iFrame.